# 2 step login via ssh using expect

Tags: ssh, expect

I'm trying to create a script that logs in via ssh, but to make it a littler harder I have to ssh into one server and then ssh into another to get to the server I want to be on. The code I have so far works fine to get me into the first server, but doesn't work when it then tries to ssh into the next.

```
#! /usr/bin/expect -f

# set servers to ssh into
set server1 "foo"
set server2 "bar"

# get username
send_user -- "Enter username: "
expect_user -re "(.*)\n"
set user $expect_out(1,string)

# get password
# don't ouput password to the user
stty -echo
send_user -- "Enter password for \"$user\": "
expect_user -re "(.*)\n"
send_user "\n"
stty echo
set password $expect_out(1,string)

# start the login
spawn ssh $user@$server1
expect "assword:"
send -- "$password\r"

# problems happen after here

# required to ssh from the <something> into <something else>
# the host name varies, e.g. host1, host2, host3, etc.
# so this just detects the last character
expect -re "\$ $"
send -- "ssh $user@$server2\r"
# sometimes it outputs this, sometimes it doesn't
expect "(yes/no)?"
send -- "yes\r"
expect "assword:"
send -- "$password\r"

interact
```

It's the same username and password for both servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made mistake in

```
expect -re "\$ $"; # WRONG
```

If you want to match the literal dollar sign along with end of line, you have to use

```
expect -re "\\\$ $"; # CORRECT
```

which will match literal dollar sign and a space at the line end.

Alternatively, to match some common known prompt, you can define a variable like

```
set prompt "#|>|%|\\\$ $"; # We escaped the `$` symbol with backslash to match literal '$'
```

The last dollar sign represents line-end.

While the `expect` is used, we have to accompany with `-re` flag to specify that as a regular expression.

```
expect -re $prompt
```

If we don't know whether a particular word will arrive in the output or if we are not sure about the order of occurrence, then it is advised to use `exp_continue`.

```
send -- "ssh $user@$server2\r"
# sometimes it outputs this, sometimes it doesn't
expect {
        "(yes/no)?" {send -- "yes\r";exp_continue}
        "ssword:" {send -- "$password\r"}
}
expect -re $prompt
```

Comment: Nice answer. For the regex, I usually use different quotes: `expect -re {\$ $}`